# How to name every row of 100*2500 matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

currently i am working with a matrix. The dimension of the matrix is 100*2500. I need to assign each row the matrix to a new variable. How i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign each row to a vector as follows:

```
row1 = matrix(1,:);
```

That will store the whole first row of `matrix` in `row1`.

To do this "automatically", you can store all the vectors containing each row in a cell array, for example:

```
for k = 1:size(matrix,1) %For each row
    rows{k} = matrix(k,:); %Store the k-th row in the k-th element of the cell array
end
```

Comment: this will give a cell array. But i need a row matrix. thank for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by row matrix? I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: sorry. what i meant was row vector.

Comment: let me clear it. let data = ones(3,5); so i want row1= data(1,:), row2=data(2,:) and row3= data(3,:).

Comment: @MMIslam try this code 
`for i=1:size(matrix,1); eval(sprintf('row%d = matrix(i,:);', i)); end;`

However, first, this method is very very computationally inefficient. And second, this kind of question is off-topic.